# is it a good idea to throw part of a mushroom in the bottom of every plant hole?

Tags: planting, mushrooms

As a hobby mycologist I get a lot of mushrooms in my yard, and I was wondering if it's a bad idea to throw part of a mycorrhizal fungi in the bottom of every hole that I drop a plant into so it can connect to the environment better.

Comment: Sure I don't see why not, go for it.

Comment: The only parts of a mycorrhizal fungus that you are likely to be able to "throw in the bottom of a hole" are the fruiting bodies, which are not the parts that are beneficial to plants. Any reasonably fertile soil will be full of them anyway - and don't forget there are estimated to be 20,000+ different species, so adding a lump of just one species might not be very useful. On the other hand, it's unlikely to do much harm.

Comment: I'm thinking about wine caps because I've heard they're very helpful to the plants.